# Parse json string in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

A simple one, but I've just not yet been able to wrap my head around parsing nested lists and json structures in Python...

Here is the raw message I am trying to parse.

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "1b9c0952-3fe3-4ab4-a8ae-26bd5d3445f8",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBy40IsvNDy33dOhn4KB8+7apBecWpSuw5OgL9sw/Nf+tM2esLgqmWjGsd4n0oqB",
            "body": "{\n  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\n  \"MessageId\" : \"dce5c301-029f-55e1-8cee-959b1ad4e500\",\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:062497424678:vid\",\n  \"Message\" : \"ChiliChallenge.mp4\",\n  \"Timestamp\" : \"2020-01-16T07:51:39.807Z\",\n  \"SignatureVersion\" : \"1\",\n  \"Signature\" : \"oloRF7SzS8ipWQFZieXDQ==\",\n  \"SigningCertURL\" : \"https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-a.pem\",\n  \"UnsubscribeURL\" : \"https://sns.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:062478:vid\"\n}",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1579161099897",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIY4XD42",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1579161099945"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "1f246d643af4ea232d6d4c91f",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:062497424678:vid",
            "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the Message in the body section, ending up with a string as "ChiliChallenge.mp4\"

Thanks! 
Essentially I just keep getting either TypeError: string indices must be integers or parsing the body but not getting any further into the list without an error.

Here's my attempt:

```
import json

with open ("event_testing.txt", "r") as myfile:
    event=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    str(event)
    event = json.loads(event)
    key = event['Records'][0]['body']
    print(key)
```

Comment: What about `event['Records'][0]['body']['Message']`?

Comment: You already know how to read json as a string, what happened when you tried to do the same with `key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `json.loads` to load string

```
with open ("event_testing.txt", "r") as fp:
    event = json.loads(fp.read())
    key = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])['Message']
    print(key)


'ChiliChallenge.mp4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your message is phrase,
I rebuild your code like:

`phrase_2 = phrase["Records"]
print(phrase_2[0]["body"])`

Then it works clearly. Because beginning of the Records, it looks like an array so you need to organized it.